# HTML5 Video not playing in iOS Simulator Safari

Tags: ios, html, ipad, html5-video, ios-simulator

I'm using the iOS Simulator to test a website on iPhone and iPad. I have a `video` tag that works in every other browser but not iOS Safari (in the simulator - I don't have actual iPhone/iPad). I created the video tag from here: http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody#video-code

```
<!-- first try HTML5 playback: if serving as XML, expand `controls` to `controls="controls"` and autoplay likewise -->
<!-- warning: playback does not work on iOS3 if you include the poster attribute! fixed in iOS4.0 -->
<video width="640" height="360" controls>
    <!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
    <source src="testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><!-- Safari / iOS video    -->
    <source src="testvideo.ogv" type="video/ogg" /><!-- Firefox / Opera / Chrome10 -->
    <!-- fallback to Flash: -->
    <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player.swf">
        <!-- Firefox uses the `data` attribute above, IE/Safari uses the param below -->
        <param name="movie" value="player.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=myimage.jpg&amp;file=testvideo.mp4" />
        <!-- fallback image. note the title field below, put the title of the video there -->
        <img src="__VIDEO__.JPG" width="640" height="360" alt="test title"
             title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object>
</video>
<!-- you *must* offer a download link as they may be able to play the file locally. customise this bit all you want -->
<p> <strong>Download Video:</strong>
    Closed Format:  <a href="testvideo.mp4">"MP4"</a>
    Open Format:    <a href="testvideo.ogv">"Ogg"</a>
</p>
```

What could be causing the issue? Is it the simulator or the video? Or the code?

**EDIT: When I click the video image to play, it opens quicktime and then pops up an error message: "The operation could not be completed"**

Comment: I have used this url - http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html from the link you shared. video works fine, i have loaded this url in webview and video appears in full screen mode. what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @UttamSinha When I click the video image to play, it opens quicktime and then pops up an error message: "The operation could not be completed"

Comment: @UttamSinha When I try that same page (the camendesign/....test.html) I get the same error as with my video. Maybe it is the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Check the screenshot. Video works fine in iOS simulator. Refer url - http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html

[image]

Comment: I get the error for this video: http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html